# Node value in graph datastructure

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a quick question:

I'm in the Datastructure course and we are writing a program to find distance between cities. It says that we should put the city names as keys (prefereably using a hashtable) and the nodes as values in the table. I'm wondering if the nodes have a value that I assign or are they just placeholders in the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node would be the basic structure (that you'd create) that would represent each (one) city and also encapsulate various pointers required to be stored with each city.

```
struct CityNode {
    char *cityName;

    // Other data

    // Various pointers required by the algorithm.
}
```

You may name it anything, but it's a norm to call them nodes.

Now you can access name of city when you have a node. But when you need node when a name is given, that would be impossible.
Therefore, for easy access to nodes, you were asked to create a hashtable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good question to ask your professor. Normally, a node in this kind of problem would probably be some kind of object or data structure that specifies what other nodes (cities) it connects to, and probably the distance to each adjacent node. So you could store the entire node in your hash table, or you could store them statically somewhere else and just point pointers to them in the hash table. If any of this doesn't make sense, you can try providing more details in the question, or my best advice is to meet your professor for a little extra guidance.